# ng serve --proxy-config proxyconfig.json not working

Tags: node.js, angular, proxy, mean-stack

I'm building an app using MEAN stack. I'm using Proxy config file to make requests to the backend which is written in Node JS.

**proxyconfig.json**

```
{
  "/api/*": {
   "target": "https://localhost.com:3333",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/api": "https://localhost.com:3333/api"
    }
  }
}
```

Code in Component file

```
  this.http.get("/api/posts",{responseType: 'text'})
  .subscribe(
      data =>
      {
           console.log('successs');
      },
      error =>
      {

          console.log(error);

      }
  );
```

Code in Node JS server

```
 app.get('/api/posts', function(req, res) {

  console.log('Posts Api Called');

  res.status(200).send({ data: 'somedata' });

});
```

I'm getting 500 error when I inspect the request from Chrome. The `GET` method is not getting called at all. What could be the cause?

Comment: I don’t think you need to rewrite the path in your proxy config file

Comment: tried without `pathRewrite`, doesnt work either

Comment: Do you really use **https** on your local server?

Comment: Also to understand that it is an issue on FE, you can try to call from browser directly your **get** endpoint and check whether it works at all

Comment: @AmirArbabian I use https on my local server and the Endpoint works fine when I try it in browser directly.

Comment: I don't know then, try to remove `{responseType: 'text'}` from your **get** call, just to check

Comment: check your api call in chrome dev tools’ network tab, tell us what you see there

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I made a silly mistake and this worked for me.

```
{
    "/api": {
    "target": "https://localhost:3333/api",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "pathRewrite": {"^/api" : ""}
  }
}
```